# Edit row in PrimeFaces dataTable does not update object

Tags: jsf, primefaces

With a PrimeFaces dataTable I try to edit a row. But when I click on the 'Save Row' button, the old value is send to the bean.

I tried to copy the database object to a normal pojo, but still the old value is send to the bean.

I use PrimeFaces 12

XHTML:

```
    <h:form id="form">
      <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true"/>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1><h:outputText value="#{txt['rider.title']}"/></h1>

        <p:dataTable id="dt_riders" class="table table-striped" value="#{riderView.allRiders}"
                     var="rider" editable="true">
          <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{riderView.onRowEdit}" update=":form:msgs"/>
          <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{riderView.onRowCancel}" update=":form:msgs"/>

          <p:column headerText="#{txt['rider.header.id']}">
            <h:outputText value="#{rider.id}"/>
          </p:column>
          <p:column headerText="#{txt['rider.header.name']}">
            <p:cellEditor>
              <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{rider.name}"/>
              </f:facet>
              <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText id="nameInp" value="#{rider.name}"/>
              </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
          </p:column>
          <!-- and a few more -->
          <p:column>
            <p:rowEditor editTitle="Edit Row" cancelTitle="Cancel Edit" saveTitle="Save Row"/>
          </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
      </div>
    </h:form>
```

The bean:

```
@ViewScoped
@Named("riderView")
public class RiderView implements Serializable {
    private final RiderEjb riderEjb;
    private final SecurityOfficer securityOfficer;

    public RiderView() {
        this(null, null);
    }
    @Inject
    public RiderView(RiderEjb riderEjb, SecurityOfficer securityOfficer) {
        this.riderEjb = riderEjb;
        this.securityOfficer = securityOfficer;
    }

    public List<Rider> getAllRiders() {
        return riderEjb.findAll(securityOfficer.getTeam());
    }

    public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent<Rider> event) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Rider Edited", String.valueOf(event.getObject().getName()));
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        riderEjb.addOrUpdate(event.getObject());
    }

    public void onRowCancel(RowEditEvent<Rider> event) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Edit Cancelled", String.valueOf(event.getObject().getName()));
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }
}
```

The Java object (getters and setters are generated by Lombok):

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Rider extends AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private Double weight;
    private String gpxNames;
}
```

Comment: Works in the showcase https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml. Please create a reproducer. https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test

Comment: show us `Rider2`

Comment: @grigouille Excuse me, Rider2 was an experiment with a Rider that was not an Entity, that did not work either. I replaced it with the code for the normal Rider

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the method `getAllRiders()`. That calls the bean to gather the riders from the database. I changed it to retrieve all those riders from the database in a new `@PostConstruct init()` method.
Thanks to Jasper de Vries, I used the primefaces-test to pinpoint the problem.